# How to get google maps api to extend from android.app.Fragment instead of Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

The problem i have is I'm trying to get google maps `api` working in my app. had it working before but i have since added the navigation drawer to my app which uses a different type of fragment **android.app.Fragment** and the map uses `FragmentActivity` when i add the code to the fragment class and extend `android.app.Fragment` i get the following `errors` .

> Error:(46, 63) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()
>
> Error:(66, 48) error: incompatible types: MyMapFragment cannot be converted to Context
>
> Error:(66, 171) error: incompatible types: MyMapFragment cannot be converted to Context

**Here is my Fragment class for the map**

```
public class MyMapFragment extends android.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

public MyMapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    return view;

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Heres the fragment_map.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="wit.ie.mightyangler.Fragment.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: How is that even compiling? The code below your return will never be read

Answer (score 0):

Use not support version

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and in xml

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```